# Region-specific user-submitted content on a Facebook page

Tags: facebook, facebook-pages

I am in a process of setting up a page for a band which would have geographically-diverse fan base. What I am after is:

1. Have each language-specific community see only the comments made in the same language. For example, an English fan would see community discussion in English and a German person in German (based on FB language/region)
2. I would still like to have a single page for all of the activity to make it easier to have larger 'like' count.

Is there any way to achieve the above or do I need to create two separate pages?

Answer (score 1):

On your page go to **Edit Page » Edit Settings**.  In the **Manage Permissions** tab ensure that **Post privacy gating** is checked and click **Save Changes**.  This will allow you to restrict posts to specific regions or languages.

[image: Post privacy gating checkbox]

When you post, click on **Public** and then **Location/Language**, set the location or language that you want for that post, and press **Gate Post**.  Only those in that region or with that language setting will be able to see the post.

[image: Location/Language]
[image: Control Who Can See Post dialog]

An alternative is to target your post by language, location, or other criteria.  The difference between gating and targeting is that targeting still allows others outside of the targeting criteria to see the post, for example if they visit the page directly or if one of their friends from a different region likes it or comments on it.  Gating hides the post completely from those outside the gating criteria.

[image: Target vs. Gate]

Comment: thanks, this is great! However, what I was after was filtering of the user-submitted content. For example, if a fan posts in German on the page, I would not like to see the comment when viewing the English version. Is that possible?

Comment: Fans do not normally see posts by other fans in their News Feed anyway, unless a friend has posted it or liked or commented.  In the case of someone visiting the page directly, I don't think you can have it display only posts from others with the same language setting, but you can disallow posts from others, hide them on your page, or show them only if the visitor chooses "Posts by Others".

Comment: You could hide posts by others or just keep them in the "Posts by Others" section where most people will not look, and when a fan posts something good then share it as the page with the appropriate language gate, giving credit to the fan and adding any comments you may have.